# regular express match e-mail domain

Tags: asp.net, regex, email

How would I use regular expression to check e-mail addresses, ensuring that the domain in the e-mail is a specific domain. I am using asp.net

Example. My company name is **ABC** and all employee e-mail addresses are on **domain abc.com** (e.g. john.doe**@abc.com** or donal.smith**@abc.com**)

My application should not allow the entry of an email address ending with a domain other than @abc.com. Entry of email john.oh**@gmail.com *should fail*** but john.oh**@abc.com *should pass***.

The domain can be mixed case, upper or lower. @Abc.com, @abc.com @ABC.com etc should be allowed.

I think the . is throwing me off.

Thanks for taking a look

Comment: This can be matched with a ridiculously simple regex - I mean, literally, the string that you wish to match, with the dot escaped. What's the specific problem you are having?

Comment: Why do you need regex? You can just use `email.ToLower().EndsWith("abc.com")`, assuming email is a string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all the domain names with this regex.

```
"(?i)^.+@abc[.]com$"
```

or

```
"^.+@[Aa][Bb][Cc][.][Cc][Oo][Mm]$"
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use the exact expression, it fails. When I use ^.+@abc[.]com$" it works when @abc.com but no when the case is different. Doing some searching, it appears that (?i) should allow for case insensitive matching, but it is not working for me in Visual Studio asp.net.

Comment: Thanks Avinash, that does the trick and taught me a few things about regex, much appreciated.